# Bootstrap 3 - 100% height of custom div inside column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have two columns in a row.

One contains an image using `class="img-responsive"` for fluid image and the other column next to has a custom div block.

My question is how to get this custom div's height 100%. Below didn't work for me.

```
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

If I set fixed value in height, it won't play nicely with the 
column containing image as the image resizes height when the viewport size changes.

I can get the columns heights equal by doing something like the following as suggested by previous questions.

```
class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.row {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

But my case is slightly different that I need to use custom div inside the column that
sets equal height with the image height, not the parent divs (columns).

Here is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/4z3PE/)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with height: 100%; ? If so, what did you see?

Comment: yes, I've tried that also. Nothing happened.

Comment: can you provide Js fiddle??

Comment: I think I should do that..will update with fiddle soon.

Comment: I just made this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/4z3PE/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The original question is about Bootstrap 3 and that supports IE8 and 9 so Flexbox would be the best option but it's not part of my answer due the lack of support, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and toggle the IE box. Pretty bad, eh?

## 2 ways:

**1. Display-table:**
You can muck around with turning the row into a display:table and the col- into display:table-cell. It works buuuut the limitations of tables are there, among those limitations are the push and pull and offsets won't work. Plus, I don't know where you're using this -- at what breakpoint. You should make the image full width and wrap it inside another container to put the padding on there. Also, you need to figure out the design on mobile, this is for 768px and up. When I use this, I redeclare the sizes and sometimes I stick importants on them because tables take on the width of the content inside them so having the widths declared again helps this. You will need to play around. I also use a script but you have to change the less files to use it or it won't work responsively.

---

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/EtUBujI/2

```
  .row.table-row > [class*="col-"].custom {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
  }


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  img.img-fluid {width:100%;}

  .row.table-row {display:table;width:100%;margin:0 auto;}

  .row.table-row > [class*="col-"] {
    float:none;
    float:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
  }

  .row.table-row > .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .row.table-row > .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
  }


}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row table-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 custom">
                100% height to make equal to ->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 image-col">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=image+1" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### 2. Absolute bg div

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/aVEsUmig/2/edit

## DEMO with content above and below: http://jsbin.com/aVEsUmig/3

---

```
.content {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #ccc;

}


@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .my-row {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .img-fluid {
        width: 100%
    }
    .row.my-row > [class*="col-"] {
        position: relative
    }
    .background {
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 200%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  
    <div class="row my-row">
      
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          
        <div class="content">
          This is inside a relative positioned z-index: 1 div
          </div>

         <div class="background"><!--empty bg-div--></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-sm-6 image-col">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/777777/FFFFFF&text=image+1" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      
    </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer is clear and right on point. As you mentioned, I will need to play with this concept a bit for display on smaller devices.

Comment: IE 8 screws up all padding between the columns so you have to make a work around. Here's an idea: http://jsbin.com/EtUBujI/3/edit -- you use an ie8 hack to add :before that takes up the height of the column and put a fake divider there that mimics the padding of the columns. Being a display table, this positions based on the table, not the cell, so you have to position it once the layout is done. Play around. I ended up with a jQuery solution since IE8 was bugging me.

Comment: I added another option to this answer that probably works better in IE8 and is easier to deal with.

Comment: For the record, I think not including display: flex in this answer is super wrong. You should never use display: table when flexbox would do the job.

Answer (score 56):

I was just looking for a smiliar issue and I found this:

```
.div{
  height : 100vh;
}
```

**more info**

```
vw: 1/100th viewport width
vh: 1/100th viewport height
vmin: 1/100th of the smallest side
vmax: 1/100th of the largest side
```

Comment: `vh` is to size it with the viewport height and not the parent div

Comment: Yes it's for bootstrap and it should use viewport for it to work

Comment: Well this actually seems to work as I wanted it to with my bootstrap column, simple and good. What does vh stand for, viewport-height?

Comment: the problem if one of the sibling column get more heigh this will break

Comment: Not correct for my project, but +1 upvote for the useful info

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the height of every parent element of the one you want the height defined.

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
  <body style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;">
      <p>
        Make this division 100% height.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Article.](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm)

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/935h9/)

Comment: Here is an excelent post explaining how height works http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: Does this work with boootstrap 3, i.e. what OP asked?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make all the parents 100% and set a specific percentage for each row:

```
html, body,div[class^="container"] ,.column {
    height: 100%;
}

.row0 {height: 10%;}
.row1 {height: 40%;}
.row2 {height: 50%;}
```