# Sidebar full height, goes on top of the footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to the sidebar to go on top of the footer, using bootstrap.

Now my sidebar is only the height of the content, this is how it looks now:
[image]

If the content is longer, sidebar should extend also, stiked to the bottom.

This how it should look:
[image]

You can look here what I have so far: [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/129922)

Comment: This post might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773342/bootstrap-3-100-height-of-custom-div-inside-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This is always a tough one, but check this out. http://www.bootply.com/129939</strike>

Moved around some html, added a new class, and modified existing classes (modifications are at the top.)

Not sure if this works for you or not because it does take up the full viewport height and I don't know if that's what you were looking for. It may also need refactoring as a result of the changes.

Edit: First version doesn't scale to fit content - sorry.

Edit: New version (scales to fit *static* content; unfortunately does use Javascript) - http://www.bootply.com/130009.

Comment: well, with css works only faux columns, but I can't make it go over the footer.
javascript is a good way, but it's not working for me, because of the separate layout on content area and footer.

Comment: Hmm - not sure what you mean - what do you mean by the separate layout? Can you describe a little more in depth what the problem you're having is?