# Twitter Bootstrap aligning checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I align `<div class="checkbox">...</div>` with the `<input class="form-control" type="text" id="text">` and not the `<label>...</label>` ?

I am using the latest bootstrap.

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LYu3pGkzwAmMa5mkCQES?p=preview).

**Update:**

To be precise, I am trying to vertically middle align the entire `<div class="checkbox">...</div>` with the `<input>` tag and not the  tag's label

Comment: What input and what label? It's very confusing because your label of the input is "input", so be more clear please.

Comment: @paulalexandru I have added better tags in the question.

Comment: You have 2 labels there : 1. Checkbox is not aligned with input 2.Input . Anyway, on my browser they seem aligned to me. The checkbox with the input

Comment: @paulalexandru So the div used for the checkbox with all its contents is aligned with the <input> tag and not the input tag's label ? Because it is not. I don't think I make myself clear on what I try to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773342/bootstrap-3-100-height-of-custom-div-inside-column  this link will help you to fix your problem.

Comment: @shin So Bootstrap has nothing to help me with this and I need to fiddle with heights, padding, etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try with nested columns:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6iafYcHG9K461CiFNOpk?p=preview

Comment: I think this is the only way, even though I will have to take care of indentations since nested columns will change it.