# bootstrap 3 inherit parent div height

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my child div to inherit the parents div height

I tried in my css:

```
height: inherit;
height: 100%;
min-height: inherit;
min-height: 100%;
```

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/zA9rQ/1/)

Comment: question that has been ask a thousand time,and has nothing to do with bootstrap.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773342/bootstrap-3-100-height-of-custom-div-inside-column

Comment: the bootstrap css has nothing to do with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS 100% height with padding/margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally how I make DIVs to extend to full height:

```
  html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  .full { height: 100% }
```